# How to use for loop in apex:outputPanel?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm quite new to Salesforce coding. I have a Visualforce email template where I'd like to use a for loop.

I've used the if condition like this:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(relatedTo.XXXXX__c == 'Feb', true, false)}">
```

I'd like to know how to correctly use the for loop for outputting HTML.

I was trying to do something like this:

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < {!relatedTo.Number_of_Users__c}; i++) {
      <apex:image ..... />
      ....
      ....                                     
}
```

When I tried to save the template, I get error like this:

```
Error: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
```

I've found this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_traditional.htm?search_text=for%20loop) but it doesn't show me how to use it in an email template. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You should start by doing some Trailhead badges like this one: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals

In your case, you have to use the [`apex:repeat`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_repeat.htm) component.

Your code will be:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.Number_of_Users__c}" var="nbUser">
      <apex:image ..... />
      ....
      ....                                     
</apex:repeat>
```